# Is it possible to represent all odd and even functions by a sine and cosine series respecitively?

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-series

My textbook [1] claims that

> it is possible to represent *all* odd functions by a sine series and *all* even functions by a cosine series.

Is anyone able to provide a proof or justification for this?

[1] - *Riley, K. F.; Hobson, M. P.; Bence, S. J.*, Mathematical methods for physics and engineering. A comprehensive guide (3rd ed.) Cambridge University Press. p. 416 (2006).

Comment: If you assume that all functions can be represented as sine + cosine series, the proof is trivial.

Comment: @mikado Do functions not have to satisfy the Dirichlet conditions to be represented by a Fourier series?

Comment: The claim is **wrong**. We cannot do so with *all* functions. You first need some restrictions on the functions - they need to be $2\pi$ periodic and piecewise continuous.

Comment: Fourier series can generate only $\aleph_1$ number of functions, whereas the total number of functions is $2^{\aleph_1}$

Comment: Probably the book restricts the class of the functions. For example they are assumed to be continuous or at least piecewise-continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$d(x)  =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{$\frac{x}{2π}$ is rational} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

is even but can't be represented by a cosine series.

But I think this comment is probably correct:

> Probably the book restricts the class of the functions. For example they are assumed to be continuous or at least piecewise-continuous

The book is “Mathematical methods for **Physics and Engineering**”. Functions that arise in physics and engineering are always continuous or nearly continuous. Monstrosities like $d$ above don't have any relevance to the physical universe.

Comment: So must the functions also satisfy the Dirichlet conditions?

Comment: Yes, if they don't then they don't have a Fourier decomposition at all.  But if an even function does have a Fourier decomposition, that decomposition will be a cosine series.